# how to Create Activity or Task whenever Workflow Fires.

Tags: workflow, automation

I have written a workflow based on opportunity stage to send an email template to user. I want to track whether the workflow sends email to customer or not?

Is their any way to create a task or create an activity under opportunity , whenever workflow fires (i am using time based workflows )?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For Time based workflow you can create a task by adding under workflow actions .

Below is the help article

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005058&language=en_US

Also vote for below idea to provide automatic creation of task when emails are sent via workflow

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroKAAS